# Laravel Cashier Billing Portal Language

Tags: laravel, vue.js, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Is there any way to change the language of the stripe's billing portal with laravel cashier?

something like this

```
request()->user()->updateStripeCustomer(['preferred_locales' => ['el']]);
```

But for the billing portal

```
request()->user()->redirectToBillingPortal()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with laravel cashier, as you can't do this even with Stripe's API. The billing portal will automatically show a localized version of the portal based on the browser's default language (and as long as it is one of the languages supported https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/integrating-customer-portal#previewing-and-testing).